# Standalone components vs. translations

Tags: angular

Standalone components are simple and clean, but I have no idea how to handle the translation. It is not about to use the translate pipe or a service. It is about where to configure the content.

The project was structured in multiple apps and libs and the libs in modules. The module bring there translation files, as soon as module is used the translation file is bundled into the resulting application. There is an overhead when not using all components / services of the module.

Now there is the concept of standalone components. No module means no simple way to configure the translations. Any ideas how to handle this, I guess it is not a good idea implement the translate files for each single components. And sure it is may not a good idea to have the translation with the application because I need to have the translations more than once which could be hard to handle.

I am very thankful for any good idea and advice.

Answer (score 1):

there is a workaround that worked for me. I had the same problems, with multiple modules that loaded different JSON file for @ngx-translate, depending on the url path.

For example, let's suppose that I have two different URLs path : localhost:4200/path1 and localhost:4200/path2. When I'm in /path1 I want to load the fild within the directory i18n/path1/en.JSON, while I'm in /path2 I want to load the file within i18n/path2/en.JSON.

To resolve, it's necessary to create a completely custom loader, in a file called `translate-loader.ts`

```
import { TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Router, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

export class CustomTranslateLoader implements TranslateLoader {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}

  public getTranslation(lang: string): Observable<any> {
    let routePrefix = this.router.url.includes('/path1') ? 'path1/' : 'path2/';
    let path = `./assets/i18n/${routePrefix}${lang}.json`;
    return this.http.get(path);
  }
}
```

Then, where you call the method `bootstrapApplication`, you can use this:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule, provideHttpClient, withFetch } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ApplicationConfig, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { CustomTranslateLoader } from './app/core/translate-loader';

export function createTranslateLoader(http: HttpClient, router : Router) {
  return new CustomTranslateLoader(http,  router);
}

const appConfig : ApplicationConfig = 
{
  providers : 
  [
    provideHttpClient(withFetch()) , 
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(HttpClientModule),
    importProvidersFrom
    (
      TranslateModule.forRoot(
      {
          loader : 
          { 
            provide : TranslateLoader , 
            useFactory : createTranslateLoader , 
            deps : [HttpClient , Router]
          },
          defaultLanguage : 'en'
      })
    )
  ]
};

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent , appConfig).catch((err) =>console.log(err));
```

Comment: I cam across with. this approach too, but my problem to solve is, that the component or module or what ever is inanother lib (in my workspace) because we have multiple application in own workspace. some are using the component / module some not. 
I dont want to tell the develops, to find and copy a special translation to the application as soon as the import / use this component / module, because the risk they miss it is high (multiple languages and they may test one the prefered one)

Comment: Isn't there a better solution to this? Adding more /asset/.18n paths doesn't seem like a good idea. This will get messy really fast with bigger applications with a lot translations. This used to work for me without putting any translations into assets folder and scattering them through modules that translations are related to. And now.... Now I cannot even get this to work, especially when navigating to other pages since translations are not getting loaded for some reason